# Approval for background location on Android?

Tags: android, qt, google-play, android-manifest, android-permissions

I developed an Android App with Qt. Some time ago I got an E-Mail "Approval for background location" from Play Store. I'm not familiar with Java and I don't understand the problem.
My App uses GPS only if the app is visible (in foreground), but not if it is invisible (background).

My Manifest.xml looks like this:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="23" android:targetSdkVersion="28"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING"/>
```

Now I found on Play Store

```
...the ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION permission only affects an app's access to location when it runs in the background.
```

For me this means because I don't use ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION my App only uses GPS if it is visible (foreground). So what is the problem? Thanks...

Comment: It is not simple issue. Android 10/11 have strict restrictions on the use of location permissions.

Read these docs first. 
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9799150 https://developer.android.com/training/location/permissions#background

What android component do you use to request GPS? How do you check that you app is in background? Please provide code of GPS subsription from you app.

Comment: As I mentioned, I'm not familiar with Java. Unfortunately I don't know something about "code of GPS subsription" from my app. It's a camera app with AR and thus it needs very precise gps postion data. And I'm not able to check if my app is in background. Why is this not automatically done by Android via the ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION permission? Thks...

Comment: These docs should help you which location permission you need for your app. You should not use ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION permission. Do you use any framework with Qt? Please, provide you gradle dependencies and androidManifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem. I double checked my *AndroidManifest.xml*, there was no *ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION* in it.

I use the QGeoPositionInfoSource from C++ to get periodic location updates. I never called the **stopUpdates()** function, that had to be fixed. It must be called when the app goes to background, e.g.: *onPause*.

Here is a very useful video with the clue, and some other useful reading material:

- https://youtu.be/xTVeFJZQ28c?t=394
- https://developer.android.com/training/location/permissions
- https://youtu.be/xTVeFJZQ28c?t=394
- https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background-location-limits

There is a signal **QGuiApplication::applicationStateChanged** which can be utilized for this, an example code:

```
if (const auto *const gui =
        qobject_cast<const QGuiApplication *const>(qApp)) {
  connect(gui, &QGuiApplication::applicationStateChanged, this,
          [&](Qt::ApplicationState state) {
            switch (state) {
            case Qt::ApplicationState::ApplicationActive:
              source->startUpdates();
              break;
            default:
              source->stopUpdates();
            }
          });
}
```

The **source** is a pointer for the *QGeoPositionInfoSource*.